# Render v-html as VUE components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a VUE component preview (similar to JSFiddle/CodePen), in VUE.

The VUE container that previews the component is this:

```
<quickpreview v-html="code"></quickpreview>
```

The content of `code` is **raw** HTML, let's say this:

```
<PRE-TASK>
    <STEP>
        <INSTRUCTION>
            <REF-DS>das Teleskopieren ...</REF-DS>.</INSTRUCTION>
    </STEP>
    <STEP>
        <INSTRUCTION>
            <REF-DS>Sicherheitsanweisungen ...</REF-DS>.</INSTRUCTION>
    </STEP>
    <STEP>
        <INSTRUCTION>
            <REF-DS>Den Teleskopwagen ...</REF-DS>.</INSTRUCTION>
    </STEP>
</PRE-TASK>
```

Note that both `<STEP>` and `<INSTRUCTION>` are valid components:

```
components: {
  'step': Step // Step.vue exists
  'instruction': Instruction // Instruction.vue exists
}
```

**What is the easiest way to force `<quickpreview>` to show HTML content as the VUE components defined above?**

Comment: [Check this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [**`Vue.compile()`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) to *compile a dynamic template* into a `Vue component` and use `render()` in `<quick-preview />` to render the result.

```
// define the available components
Vue.component('steps', {...})
Vue.component('step', {...})
Vue.component('instruction', {...})

// the <quick-preview /> component
Vue.component('quick-preview', {
  props: ['code'],
  render(h){
    // render a 'container' div
    return h('div', [
      h(Vue.compile(this.code)) // compile and render 'code' string
    ])
  }
})


// then you can use it as
new Vue({
  data(){
    return {
      code: '...'
    }
  },
  template: '<quick-preview :code="code" />'
})
```

Example on [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/105973/)

Note: You **need** a **full build** of Vue.js to use `template` at runtime because the *slimmed down*, *runtime-only* build doesn't contain the compiler! More info can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds)

Comment: BEWARE! this  may introduce XSS vulnerabilites in your code! make sure you only render 'trusted' code this way, or sanitize the html somehow before rendering

Comment: Thanks, but with correction. As `Vue.compile` can contain only exactly one root element, it would be more appropriate to `render(h) { const div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = this.code; return h(Vue.compile(div.outerHTML)); }`